# I typed "python3 manage.py runserver" in the python terminal in Pycharm but this message occurred

Tags: python, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2AoA.png)

The screenshot from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I sooner had the same issue : you are using microsoft windows, so consider typing `py -3 manage.py runserver` instead of `python3 manage.py runserver`. `python3` is the command for linux, and maybe that is weird, but the windows version uses `py -3` instead of `python3`.
Hope it helps !